# Eureka + zuul + micro serviços + thymeleaf - Problema ao carregar os webjars

Tags: spring, thymeleaf, cloud

Estou criando um sistema baseado na arquitetura de micro serviços com o seguinte fluxo.

eureka porta(8888)

zuul porta(8080)

stu_usuario (8081) /Usuario/**

stu_veiculo (8082) /Veiculo/**

Pelo que eu entendi o zuul é um gateway onde quando for solicitado por exemplo `localhost:8080/Usuario/listar` ele irar no serviço `stu_usuario` e me retornará a página desejada até ai tudo bem, mas quando comecei a usar alguns `.js` e `.css` essa requisição não consegue carregar pois elá tenta carregar os arquivos no host 8080 mas eles só existem no 8081.

```
application.properties
    spring.application.name=zuul
zuul.add-host-header=true

server.tomcat.remote-ip-header=x-forwarded-host

# configurações do serviço usuario
zuul.routes.stu_usuario.path=/Usuario/**
zuul.routes.stu_usuario.url=http://localhost:8081
zuul.routes.stu_usuario.serviceId=stu_usuario
zuul.routes.stu_usuario.stripPrefix=false
zuul.routes.stu_usuario.sensitive-headers=Cookie,Set-Cookie,Authorization

# configurações do serviço veiculo

zuul.routes.stu_veiculo.path=/Veiculo/**
zuul.routes.stu_veiculo.url=http://localhost:8082
zuul.routes.stu_veiculo.serviceId=stu_veiculo
zuul.routes.stu_veiculo.stripPrefix=false
zuul.routes.stu_veiculo.sensitive-headers=Cookie,Set-Cookie,Authorization

eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://localhost:8888/eureka
eureka.client.register-with-eureka=true

server.port=8080
```

springbootapplication

```
@SpringBootApplication 
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@EnableZuulProxy
public class Configuracao {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SpringApplication.run(Configuracao.class, args);
   }    
   @Bean
   public PreFilter preFilter() {
      return new PreFilter();
   }
   @Bean
   public PostFilter postFilter() {
      return new PostFilter();
   }
   @Bean
   public ErrorFilter errorFilter() {
      return new ErrorFilter();
   }
   @Bean
   public RouteFilter routeFilter() {
      return new RouteFilter();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Cara eu sugiro utilizar o *Spring Cloud Config*, fica até melhor para alterar as *properties* dos projetos. Quanto aos *.js* e *.css* do ponto de vista arquitetural é melhor você colocar os mesmo em um repositório de forma que toda as alterações nos arquivos não necessitem de que você pare a execução das aplicações.